# Selenium xpath not showing elements in chrome it is working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).
until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy( 
By.xpath( "//div[@id='policyForm']//descendant::input" ) ) );
```

The above line returning 0 results in selenium.
But in chrome it is showing all input elements.

Comment: If there where no results it would have failed with `TimeoutException`. Please share what exactly happened.

Comment: Form has loaded before time

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: In chrome console i'm getting results but in selenium i'm not

Comment: This is what you wrote in the question. However, if there aren't any matches `WebDriverWait` will throw an exception, it won't return an empty list. You need to share the actual code/results (with the stuck trace if you have any exception) otherwise we can't really help you.